# How to verify if all the queries inside a test.sql file are executed successfully through shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell, sh

I have a `q.sql` file that has queries like

```sql
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE student SET gender = 'f' WHERE gender = 'm';

.
.
UPDATE student SET rollno = '03' WHERE rollno = '003';
```

This .sql file is executed through a shellscript:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass DB < q.sql
```

The command is executed even when one of the queries in `q.sql` file has failed. Now I want to verify if all the queries are updated successfully.

I tried to `echo $?` but it always prints 0, i.e command successful, even if the one of the queries in `q.sql` has failed.

```
mysql -uuser -ppass DB < q.sql
echo $?
```

If query fails I want it to print "failed" or stop the further execution of the shellscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `bash`, you can use the `set -e` in your script and execute each line of your mysql script using `-e` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
while read line; do
   mysql -uuser -ppass DB -e "$line"
done < q.sql
```

For information `set --help` shows:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

and the `man mysql` page:

> --execute=statement, -e statement
>   Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that produced with --batch. See Section 4.2.3.1, "Using Options on the Command Line", for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the output in a file for further processing:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass DB < q.sql > mysql.out
```

If you have a query that produces a lot of output, you can run the output through a pager rather than watching it scroll off the top of your screen:

```
mysql -uuser -ppass DB < q.sql | more
```

If you want to get the interactive output format in batch mode, use `mysql -t`. To echo to the output the statements that are executed, use `mysql -v`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html